# Particular Data extract(Date)

Tags: python, pandas, dataset, row

I have a dataset that has a flow chart and a messy date. date contains the year, month, and day, respectively (4 digits, 6 digits, 8 digits).

```
 Name Color date
0   K   A   2011
1   Y   B   201411
2   B   C   20151231
3   B   A   2019
4   C   B   201911
5   A   A   20120507
6   Q   G   20130601
```

I want to extract only the dataset for 2019 from this dataset(row). How can I do this? For example, I want the output as below

```
 Name Color date
0   B   A   2019
1   C   B   201911
```

Comment: Always post your code/data as [text and not as image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: You can achieve this `startswith` command. Check examples here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-pandas-series-str-startswith/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df[df['date'].astype('str').str.startswith('2019')]
```

df contains the table /data you have posted.

Comment: I got an error -> AttributeError: Can only use .str accessor with string values!

Comment: @ybin Please use the edited code above now. You got the error because the dates were not in str format which I did now

Answer (score 0):

It does not look like your date column is consistent, e.g. some are year, others are year and month. If year is always the first four digits, you can make the column a string, slice, and filter to the year you want, assuming your data is called 'df':

```
df['date'] = df['date'].astype(str)
year = df['date'].str.slice(0,4)
df[year == '2019']   # your desired rows
```

Comment: I edit my question can you check it? I want to keep the rows..